# Failed to use namespace correctly in my .cpp file

Tags: c++

I declare a namespace `MYTIME` in `mytime.h` file.

```
#include<ostream>
#ifndef _TIME_H
#define _TIME_H

namespace MYTIME{
        class time
        {
             ...
        };
}
#endif
```

And try to use it in my `time.cpp` file,

```
#include"mytime.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace MYTIME;

time::time()
{
        years = days = hours = minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;
        months = JAN;
}
```

when I use `g++ time.cpp` to compile, errors are as follows

```
time.cpp:8:17: error: ‘MYTIME’ is not a namespace-name
 using namespace MYTIME;
                 ^~~~~~
time.cpp:8:23: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
 using namespace MYTIME;
                       ^
time.cpp:10:1: error: ‘time’ does not name a type
 time::time()

time.cpp:31:6: error: ‘time’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
 void time::addSec(long int s)
time.cpp: In function ‘void addSec(long int)’:
time.cpp:34:7: error: ‘seconds’ was not declared in this scope
  m = (seconds + s) / 60;
       ^~~~~~~
time.cpp:34:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘useconds_t’
  m = (seconds + s) / 60;
       ^~~~~~~
       useconds_t
   ... // many same errors
```

where am i going wrong? and how to fix it? Looking for help.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `mytime.h` is actually included correctly? Are you writing `namespace MYTIME` in the correct file? Is that _all_ of the errors displayed?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that the `mytime.h` is included, there are lots of same errors because class `time` cannot be identified correctly.

Comment: Identifiers starting with an `_` are reserved, iirc. Don't start your definitions with one.

Comment: Regarding underscore prefixes, I know they're reserved in C, but I am not aware of this being enforced in C++ -- is it?  I have always avoided using them but more out of habit than anything else.

Comment: @paddy, it's not enforced; however, they're reserved for the compiler, so you will end up with name conflicts. Don't have the standard with me, but I think it's simply starting with `_` though it may be followed by a capital. can't remember.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_TIME_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header guard is using a name that is already defined.  As a result, your namespace and class is *never* declared.

A simple test demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
#ifdef _TIME_H
    std::cout << "Well, well, well...\n";
#endif
}
```

You would expect this program to have no output, but when compiled with g++ and run, this program outputs:

```
Well, well, well...
```

To solve this, you should use more uniquely named headers, and don't attempt to use naming conventions employed by the standard library.  In particular, prefixing with an underscore is generally not a good idea.

If your compiler supports `#pragma once` you may wish to consider using that instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, That indeed works, but there are some new errors occurred, looks like `time` causes ambiguity, but the `time` is in namespace MYTIME, why the error still happened?

Comment: Undoubtedly you will have errors in new code that has never been compiled.  Your task is to work through the errors and fix them.  That is outside the scope of your question, which was asking about a specific error that you were having difficulty diagnosing.

Comment: Ambiguity of commonly used names is a side-effect of importing entire namespaces willy-nilly.  I personally do not use `using namespace` clauses, for this precise reason.  I prefer to import specific names as aliases (with `using` clauses or `typedef`) and fully-qualify everything else.  For your definitions in the CPP file, the entire class implementation should be wrapped in `namespace MYTIME { ... }` instead.

Comment: @Yongy-vers, remove `using namespace std;`  that will lead to name conflicts too.